# AutoSelectTextBox in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am looking AutoSelectTextBox in windows phone as like the one in wpf toolkit?

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AutoSelectTextBox&referringTitle=Documentation

Can anyone please help me on this with a sample custom control code or with any useful links or blogs??

Regards,
Ganesan S

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but if you just want the TextBox to automatically select all content when "selected", you could just use the `GotFocus` event to set the selection.

Like this:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="AutoSelectLikeTextBoxGotFocus" />
```

With the event handler like:

```
private void AutoSelectLikeTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;

    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

You could wrap this in your own class that extends TextBox to make it more easily re-usable.

Comment: I have created a custom control of my own and resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Mawy.